# What format is this data in?

Tags: file-formats

I ran into a file today that is in a format I'm unfamiliar with, and I'm hoping that someone can identify it.

The file extension is CTZ, but the only file type I found on Google with that extension was the "Custody Toolbox Zip" file extension (which is software unrelated to GIS).

Here are a couple of lines from the file (all of the lines are in this format). The whitespace is all space characters, not tabs.

```
00000 000       0000CANADA                          +1285448500+4308048100+0001891000+0728293500+7050177200+0002341100+0557155000+7257869800+0001302700
10000 000       0000NEWFOUNDLAND - TERRE-NEUVE      +0024419500+0340743500+0001395400+0014446000+0243530500+0001685800+0009974000+0097218800+0000974700
10000 000       6999NFLD./T.-N. CT - SR S/TOTAL     +0007789500+0138134200+0001773300+0004317000+0093599600+0002168200+0003472500+0044536500+0001282500
```

...

```
59935A9350005.002412VICTORIA                        +0000188000+0003855300+0002050700+0000096000+0002484500+0002588000+0000092000+0001372500+0001491900
59935A9350006.002413VICTORIA                        +0000109500+0002311900+0002111300+0000056000+0001599600+0002856400+0000053500+0000709900+0001326900
```

Thanks!

Update: After some more Googling, I found this [mailing list post](http://www.listserv.uga.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind0201D&L=sas-l&P=38094) of a person with very similar data, but I couldn't garner the format from that conversation.

Update 2: The data was acquired via the Statistics Canada [Data Liberation Initiative](http://www.statcan.gc.ca/dli-idd/dli-idd-eng.htm). It sounds like it came from an FTP site that requires authentication, so I can't provide access to the files.

Comment: Where did you find the data?  What was it's source?  The more info you can provide, the more rapidly you are likely to get an answer.

Comment: What is the source of the data? (other than being Canadian)

Comment: I work in a library, and the file was sent to me by a patron who was asking for help finding a GIS application that can read it. I've asked her where she got it and will update when I get a response.

Comment: @AndreSilva Done.

Comment: That listserv is "SAS(r) Discussion" so it may be SAS or R. (Alternatively, it's some obscure data file that somebody was trying to *open* with SAS or R...)

Comment: I think, after some googling of my own, that the CTZ format is from the CyberTracker software: http://www.cybertracker.org/software/introduction

Comment: Thanks for the excellent detective work, everyone! I'll try downloading CyberTracker and see if it can read the data.

Comment: I tried opening the file with Cybertracker, but I got the following error message: "CT11 Error importing database files
 Cabinet file does not have the correct format [0x0002]".

Comment: @Erica That does seem like a definite possibility, but I unfortunately don't have those applications to try

Comment: I wonder if the data is formatted for version 2 rather than version 3, and, if so, whether that's causing the error. This page has a link to a "ConvertCTZ" program, that apparently upgrades CTZ files from version 2 to version 3: http://www.steventonconsulting.com/CyberTracker2.aspx. Note that it also has a link to download build 2.79 of CyberTracker, which would be another option for you.

Comment: @nmpeterson Good suggestion, but unfortunately version 2 won't install on 64 bit Windows and the converter tool apparently needs version 2 to be installed in order for it to be run :-\.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a fixed-width text file. The format is easy to read into Excel (or other spreadsheet), where it can be saved as a CSV or other format that is generally more GIS-friendly. You may have to change the extension from .CTZ to .TXT, or tell the spreadsheet to list "all files" when opening it. Note that some GIS software, e.g. [TNTmips](http://www.microimages.com), can easily import fixed-width text files.

However, without a header row or metadata that specify what the columns represent, it is very difficult to determine what the data is.

--- EDIT BELOW ---

Based on the link you added in your edit, the data may be both fixed width AND delimited by a plus (+), which will make it difficult to save then import into GIS software without further edits to the table. The simplest way may be to first open the file in a plain text editor (e.g. [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)), search-and-replace each plus with a few spaces, save, and then open the file in a spreadsheet as a fixed width text file.

Comment: fixed width plus delimiters is easy to deal with, just tell excel there's a one-character column where the "+"s are and then hide those columns

Comment: If the pluses are added to separate columns, then deleting those columns would be better than hiding them, assuming the data is to be saved to a CSV or XLS to be imported into GIS software.

Answer (score 1):

That's Canadian census data. The format of that file is an export using a program called Beyond 20/20. I believe it mashes up census data with some internal GIS tools. If you're in a Canadian library, you should have access to that software.

Here's another example of your file: http://prod.library.utoronto.ca/datalib/codebooks/c/cc86/bsts/ct/ec86b02.sps